# Join several alpha masks on one bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, bitmapdata, blit

I have two layers of bitmaps:
1st - some random image
2nd - bitmap filled with black color that covers 1st bitmap
Also I have a mask bitmap. 
I trying to make something like this
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13089585/so/001.jpg
But I get something like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13089585/so/002.jpg
I tryed to do this using `BitmapData::copyPixels`, `BitmapData::copyChannel` and `BitmapData::draw` with different combinations of parameters, but still can not make it... I need some method that will override alpha value on dest. bitmap, but only if this value is greater then in src. bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off, if you use a sprite instead of a bitmap as a mask, you can use `BitmapData.draw()` with `BlendMode.ERASE` to get that effect. but that will not work if you want translucency (e.g. 50% alpha).

what you can do is have the mask bitmap be black where you want the 2nd image to be transparent and and transparent elsewhere (30% alpha in the mask will become 70% alpha on 2nd bitmap).
now, create a 3rd `BitmapData` with fill color red, `draw` the mask onto 3rd `BitmapData` using `BlendMode.DARKEN`.
then, use `copyChannel()` from 3rd red to 2nd alpha.

it's not pretty, but real life never is...